# Обработка ajax событий

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть айджакс запрос

```
$('#button_save').click(function()
{

    var text = $('#text').val();
    $.post("articlejs.php", {text: text, a:a}, function (data)
    {

     $('#text').val('');
    alert(data);
    });

});
```

а так же обработчики событий

```
$('#text').ajaxError(function(){
    alert('ERROR');
    });
$('#text').ajaxStart(function(){

    alert("START");

    });
    $('#text').ajaxSuccess(function(){

    alert("COM SUCCESS")
    });
```

События почему то не обрабатываются , т.е. запрос идет, но результат обработки не выводится. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: айджакс - это таджикское имя, вероятно?

Comment: > т.е. запрос идет, но результат обработки не выводится@Sanych Goilo, вы уверены, что запрос доходит до пункта назначения и возвращает ответ? В FireBug-е это можно наблюдать?P.S. И не пользуйтесь сокращенными вариантами [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), если в этом нет нужды.

Comment: Ответ возвращается. Я уверен

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, хотелось бы узнать, как вы это определили, но поверю наслово. Тогда, раз ответ приходит, то где вы его выводите, кроме как **alert(data);**?

Comment: Да нигде я его кроме не вывожу! Пока это для меня не важно

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, у вас сегодня настроение пошутить? )) Или вас уже не интересует, как было написано в вопросе:

> т.е. запрос идет, но результат
> обработки не выводится. Подскажите
> пожалуйста в чем проблема.

Comment: не выводится Обработка ajax-событий
.ajaxSuccess()
Устанавливает пользовательскую функцию, которая будет вызвана при удачном завершении ajax-запроса.
.ajaxError()
Устанавливает пользовательскую функцию, которая будет вызвана при неудачном завершении ajax-запроса.
.ajaxStart()
Устанавливает пользовательскую функцию, которая будет вызвана перед выполнением первого ajax-запроса.

Comment: Мне пересказывать не надо )) А вот вам бы посоветовал читать [первоисточник](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){        alert('Ups!');    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var text = $('#text').val();
    $.post("articlejs.php", {text: text, a:a}, function (data)
```

У вас не должен посылаться запрос, т.к. должна возникать ошибка в консоли
 Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined 
т.е. вы пытаетесь послать переменную a, значение которой неизвестно.
в случае

```
$.post("articlejs.php", {text: text, a:'a'}, function (data)
```

все ОК.
Переписал бы запрос в виде:

```
   $.ajax({
        url:"articlejs.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: ({ text: text,a:'a' }),
        dataType: "json",
        //beforeSend : function() { alert('before send request ')},
        success:function(data) {
            alert('success request');
        },
        error: function(data) { 
                alert ('error request;');
        }
    });
```

Comment: dataType: "html" если ,например, подгружаете контент в div

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxSuccess()
> method should only be attached to
> document.

Аналогично и другие обработчики AJAX, которые вы хотите установить.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо $('#text').ajaxError(function() ....
нужно $(document).ajaxError(function() .........